# Save data in mongodb with angular and express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I use [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) for study with express and angular. I want create post. In angular

```
$scope.newsCreate = function() {
      $http.post('api/news/create', {data : $scope.newsData})
          .success(function(){
              console.log('success');
          })
          .error(function(data){
              console.log(data);
          })
  };
```

All send ok, but when i get all posts, i have only

```
0: Object
   $$hashKey: "object:4"
   __v: 0
   _id: "56460c74c757da5d68bf5e50"
```

I can't understand, how i must save it. How create db for my app..
In server side i have

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  News.create(req.body, function(err, news) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.status(201).json(news);
  });
};
```

Comment: ``req.body`` will have ``{data : $scope.newsData}``. Is that sufficient to create a new record? Perhaps the issue is with your ``News.create`` function - can you post the body for that function? Intuitively it seems like you would want to pass ``req.body.data`` to your create function rather than ``req.body``

Comment: You could try following the tutorial in: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-realtime-room-chat-app-using-node-webkit-socket-io-and-mean

Comment: @dipole_moment My post data `data: {name: "Test news", info: "text Test news", active: true}`

Comment: can you post the body of your `` News.create`` function?

Comment: `exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  News.create(req.body, function(err, news) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    return res.status(201).json(news);
  });
};`

console.log(req) - doesn't get my data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just must send data like this
`$http.post('api/news/create', $scope.newsData)`
You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like your body is empty...

I remember $http.post expect data body argument to be a string.

You should try this :

```
$http.post('api/news/create', {data : JSON.stringify($scope.newsData)})
```

Comment: I will recommend you put a breakpoint on the `News.create() ` to look if you have information in your request (inspect req object)